# Adding more \graphicspath causes images to not be found

Tags: graphics, paths

The structure of the document I'm writing is the following.

```
Top level -> Plots -> some images
                   -> 1 -> some images
                   -> 2 -> some images
                   -> 3 -> some images
                   -> 4 -> some images
```

Using the command:

```
\graphicspath{{./Plots/}{./Plots/1/}
```

Seems to work fine and allow me to add images from these two folders, however, when I try to add folders 2, 3 and 4 to the \graphicspath, I get an error for all figures saying that it cannot find the images.

Is there a way to fix this, or for the graphics package to look within all subfolders?

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, notitlepage]{article}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{setspace}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.15}
\onehalfspacing
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\graphicspath{ {/Plots/}{/Plots/1/}{/Plots/2/}{/Plots/3/}{/Plots/4/} }

\title{Report}
\author{Me}
\date{April 2013}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\thispagestyle{empty}

\newpage
\section{1}
Text.

\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{ImageFromPlots1}
\end{figure}    

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx).

Comment: its not because you need the last `}`? A full (MWE) document would ease the debugging here.

Comment: That was a typo in the original post, sorry.

I've edited the OP with a MWE. This code does not find the image located in the /Plots/1/ folder. However, if I remove folders 2, 3 and 4, from the graphics path, it works fine. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Rob: Don't load `graphicx` twice (the first is sufficient). What OS are you running? Mac? Windows? Unix?

Comment: Didn't notice I was doing that - thanks. Doesn't solve the issue.

I'm using Mac OSX 10.8.3.

Comment: @Rob: I just mentioned loading it once is sufficient, not that it would solve the problem. Using `\graphicspath` on a Mac is different from other OS's. Read section **4.5 Other commands in the `graphics` package** of the [Guide to graph­ics in LaTeX](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/required/graphics/grfguide.pdf) (p 13). It specifies trying something like `\graphicspath{ {:Plots:}{:Plots:1:}{:Plots:2:}{:Plots:3:}{:Plots:4:} }`. I can't test this myself since I'm not running on that OS.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There shouldn't be a problem.

I'm using:

```
\graphicspath{{images/}{../images/}{svg/}{gnuplot/}{gnuplot/examples/}}
```

and it works just fine. You can also get down and into another directory as you can see in my example.

You access the filesystem-root and not the subfolders (as you access `/` and not `./`). This is most likely your fault.

Try

```
\graphicspath{ {Plots/}{Plots/1/}{Plots/2/}{Plots/3/}{Plots/4/} }
```

rather than

> \graphicspath{ {/Plots/}{/Plots/1/}{/Plots/2/}{/Plots/3/}{/Plots/4/} }

On Linux/Unix systems you won't need the `./` at the beginning. Not sure about it on a Mac-system.

Comment: Your suggestion of removing the leading `./` worked. Not sure why I didn't think to try that - must be time to stop for the evening!

Thanks again.